# defining specific custom colors that will appear in the colordialog?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

is it possible in winforms, vb.net, to define the specific custom colors that will appear in the custom color boxes in colordialog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, yes. MSDN covers it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.colordialog.customcolors.aspx). The problem is that it isn't done via `Color` - you need to handle the value as BGR sets - i.e. each integer is composed of the colors as 00BBGGRR, so you left-shift blue by 16, green by 8, and use red "as is".

My VB sucks, but in C#, to add purple:

```
    using (ColorDialog dlg = new ColorDialog())
    {
        Color purple = Color.Purple;
        int i = (purple.B << 16) | (purple.G << 8) | purple.R;
        dlg.CustomColors = new[] { i };
        dlg.ShowDialog();
    }
```

reflector assures me that this is similar to:

```
Using dlg As ColorDialog = New ColorDialog
    Dim purple As Color = Color.Purple
    Dim i As Integer = (((purple.B << &H10) Or (purple.G << 8)) Or purple.R)
    dlg.CustomColors = New Integer() { i }
    dlg.ShowDialog
End Using
```

Comment: +1 for the bitwise manipulation. I really wish that MS would document this stuff better.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have more than 1 custom color, you can do this:

```
            'Define custom colors
    Dim cMyCustomColors(1) As Color
    cMyCustomColors(0) = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255) 'aqua
    cMyCustomColors(1) = Color.FromArgb(230, 104, 220) 'bright pink

    'Convert colors to integers
    Dim colorBlue As Integer
    Dim colorGreen As Integer
    Dim colorRed As Integer
    Dim iMyCustomColor As Integer
    Dim iMyCustomColors(cMyCustomColors.Length - 1) As Integer

    For index = 0 To cMyCustomColors.Length - 1
        'cast to integer
        colorBlue = cMyCustomColors(index).B
        colorGreen = cMyCustomColors(index).G
        colorRed = cMyCustomColors(index).R

        'shift the bits
        iMyCustomColor = colorBlue << 16 Or colorGreen << 8 Or colorRed

        iMyCustomColors(index) = iMyCustomColor
    Next

    ColorDialog1.CustomColors = iMyCustomColors
    ColorDialog1.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 2):

The existing example contains an error.

purple.B is a byte not an integer, so shifting it 8 or 16 bits will do nothing to the value.  Each byte first has to be cast to an integer before shifting it.  Something like this (VB.NET):

```
Dim CurrentColor As Color = Color.Purple
Using dlg As ColorDialog = New ColorDialog
    Dim colourBlue As Integer = CurrentColor.B
    Dim colourGreen As Integer = CurrentColor.G
    Dim colourRed As Integer = CurrentColor.R
    Dim newCustomColour as Integer = colourBlue << 16 Or colourGreen << 8 Or colourRed
    dlg.CustomColors = New Integer() { newCustomColour }
    dlg.ShowDialog
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

SIMPLFIED (based on Gabby)

If you know the ARGB of your target custom colors then use:

```
 '                Define custom colors
 ColorDialog1.CustomColors = New Integer() {(255 << 16 Or 255 << 8 Or 0), _
                                            (220 << 16 Or 104 << 8 Or 230), _
                                            (255 << 16 Or 214 << 8 Or 177)}
 ColorDialog1.ShowDialog()
 'where colors are (arbg) 1:   0,255,255 [aqua]
 '                        2: 230,104,220 [bright pink]
 '                        3: 177,214,255 [whatever]
```